# UWP ListView ScrollIntoView's not working correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

i have a problem, which makes me crazy:

When i'm first entering in "StopList' page, backing to Menu, and entering a 'Favourite' page and clicked and stop from the list, then ScrollIntoView not works of all time app's running.

But.. When i'm first enter into Favouritepage, and there clicked a sto then ScrollIntoView works of all time app's running.

`ListView1` is the ListView, where i want to scroll and these items are from `List<test>`;

This is code of menu, where i'm switching the page:

```
    //favourite
    private void Button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!loaded)
            return;

        if(MainWindowStopList.loaded == false)
            MainPage.gui.setPage = typeof(Pages.MainWindowStopList); //cache page if not exist, to memory

        MainPage.gui.setPage = typeof(Pages.MainWindowFav);
        MainPage.gui.setBackButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    //stops
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!loaded) return;

        if (MainWindowFav.loaded == null)
            MainPage.gui.setPage = typeof(Pages.MainWindowFav); // this same, cache if not exist;

        MainPage.gui.setPage = typeof(Pages.MainWindowStopList);

        MainPage.gui.setBackButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Code where, im navigating from Favourite to 
                     `MainWindowStopList.preparefromfav(HTMLServices.przystankinames.ElementAt(item.id));
 MainPage.gui.setPage = typeof(MainWindowStopList);`

Here are functions, where im doing something with ListView1 in `MainWindowStopList`:

```
    public MainWindowStopList()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        gui = this;

        lista2 = new List<test>();
        lista3 = new ObservableCollection<test3>();
        selectedPrzystanek = new PrzystankiNames();

        ListView1.SelectionChanged += (se, fe) =>
        {
            (se as ListView).ScrollIntoView(tempPrzystankiNames);

            //if above not works from stackoverflow
            var lv = se as ListView;
            DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
            dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            dt.Tick += (o, o1) =>
            {
                dt.Stop();
                lv.ScrollIntoView(tempPrzystankiNames);

            };
            dt.Start();
        };

        this.Loaded += (s, f) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempPrzystankiNames.name))
                ListView1.SelectedIndex = lista.IndexOf(tempPrzystankiNames);
        };
    }

    public static void preparefromfav(PrzystankiNames pr)
    {
        if(gui.ListViewSearchable.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            gui.ListViewSearchable.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            gui.ListView1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        Grid.SetColumnSpan(gui.ListView1, 1);
        gui.ResultListView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        gui.tempPrzystankiNames = pr;
        gui.showListView2(pr); //here i'm doing nothing with listview
    }

    private void reset(object sender)
    {
        navigated_from = false;
        foreach (ListView gr in MainWindowLinesInfoHours.FindVisualChildren<ListView>(this))
        {
            if (gr == sender || gr == ListView1 || gr == ListViewSearchable)
                continue;

            gr.SelectedIndex = -1; 
        }
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        reset(new object());
    }
```

So, why this scrolling not working? Do anyone have any idea?

Comment: Could you share your XAML code? A [mcve] would be better, because there are a lot of properties defined by yourself and we don't know what they refer to.

Comment: Hi! How to explain, how did i solved it..
So, I Just did a "Cache loading"; and saving a page, where i have listview to memory. In this case, everything is working, i dont know, why this solution works, thanks for answer, i Will remember about this MC&V example :)